# iOS CloudApp Integration

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, cloud

I've downloaded the iOS CloudApp API files from the CloudApp website. I would like to be able to upload images from an iOS app into the CloudApp service.  However, when I open the example application included with the API, I'm presented with a number of errors. The sample project's app delegate attempts to import a file called "Cloud.h", which cannot be found.  However, this file is visible within the project's tree structure.  Additionally, the file is imported like a framework, using `#import <Cloud.h>`, and does not import successfully when simply using `#import "Cloud.h"` either.

Finally, a file called "libcloud.a" appears in the sample project tree, but appears red, marking the item as deleted (I can't find it anywhere).  Also, the downloaded API contains a folder called "Third Party", which contains two *empty* subfolders called "IFUnicodeURL", and "JSON".  Do I need to download the contents of these folders somewhere else?

Xcode is also giving me a warning stating, "Missing dependency target 'Cloud (from Cloud.xcodeproj)'".

I've attached a screenshot of the sample project tree to the post.

Thanks in advance to any help.

[image: Project Setup]

[image: Project Tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libCloud.a is a file which is generated by the build of Cloud project. 
Have you correctly set target dependencies ? If you had, when you build TestHarness, Cloud will build before (if the source changed since the last build) and create libCloud.a. 
To set this :

- go on your TestHarness project summary
- select your target
- click on the "Build Phases" tab
- Expand "Target Dependencies" -> Cloud project must me there, if it's not, add it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was the beginning of the issue. But when I import the files for SBJson, I cannot find the file called called "JSON.h", only "SBJson.h". Also, when I try to import the "Cloud" project into my iPhone project tree, the project file just sits like a single, uneditable, unexpandable file. Any other tips?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question regarding the missing JSON files, you have to actually pull the repository down from Github instead of downloading the zip file. When you do that, you'll find that the JSON folder is populated with the files that you were missing. (See image below.) I had the same exact issue.

Let me know if you're unfamiliar with pulling repositories and I can give you a couple of tips.

http://cl.ly/3u280f3J061i0e1V120N